# Better way to find Parent row is deletable or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having

**ParentTable**

```
 PId - int    
 PDescription - varchar
```

**ChildTable**

```
CId - Int    
CDetails - Varchar    
PId - Int --  Mapped from Parent
```

I need to find whether the parent row is deletable or not while loading the data itself,  Because i don't want to allow user to delete the data with mapping. And my query below

```
select P.PId,Pdescription,Cast(Count(C.CId) as Bit)^1 "IsDeletable" 
From  ParentTable P
LEFT JOIN ChildTable C On P.Pid=C.Pid
Group By P.PId,Pdescription
```

Here Problem is Child has Many Row and it took lot of time to execute the query. Is there any other better way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

First you should make sure that you have an index on `ChildTable.Pid` and then you can rewrite your query to something like this.

```
select P.Pid,
       P.Pdescription,
       case when exists (
                        select *
                        from dbo.ChildTable as C
                        where P.Pid = C.Pid
                        )
         then cast(0 as bit)
         else cast(1 as bit)
       end as IsDeleteable
from dbo.ParentTable as P;
```

This query checks for the existence of of rows in `ChildTable` where your query is counting the number of rows for each parent. A check for existence just only have to find one row and will use the index to do one seek for each row in `ParentTable`.

[image]